# Daily average not calculating correctly as a result of Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following SQL, where I am trying to get the daily average over a month of the total count.

```
SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.INV_ITEM_ID, C.MFG_ID, C.MFG_ITM_ID, 
 A.ADJUST_TYPE, A.QTY_BASE, A.UNIT_MEASURE_STD,
 A.DT_TIMESTAMP, B.DESCR254_MIXED, A.TRANSACTION_GROUP, 
 (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.TRANSACTION_DATE,121)), A.DEPTID, B.PRICE_LIST, 
 A.DESTIN_GL_BU,  A.QTY_BASE* B.PRICE_LIST, (COUNT(*) * 1.0 / 31 ) AS 'Daily 
 Average'
FROM PS_TRANSACTION_INV A, (PS_PURCH_ITEM_ATTR B LEFT OUTER JOIN  
 PS_ITEM_MFG C ON  B.SETID = C.SETID AND B.INV_ITEM_ID = C.INV_ITEM_ID ), 
 PS_CM_ACCTG_DIST_D D 
WHERE ( A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' 
 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID 
 AND C.PREFERRED_MFG = 'Y' 
 AND A.TRANSACTION_DATE >= '05-01-2018' 
 AND A.TRANSACTION_DATE <= '05-31-2018' 
 AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = D.INV_ITEM_ID 
 AND D.TRANSACTION_GROUP = A.TRANSACTION_GROUP 
 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = '1')
GROUP BY A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.INV_ITEM_ID, C.MFG_ID, C.MFG_ITM_ID, 
 A.ADJUST_TYPE, A.QTY_BASE, A.UNIT_MEASURE_STD,
 A.DT_TIMESTAMP, B.DESCR254_MIXED, A.TRANSACTION_GROUP, 
 (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.TRANSACTION_DATE,121)), A.DEPTID, B.PRICE_LIST, 
 A.DESTIN_GL_BU,  A.QTY_BASE* B.PRICE_LIST
```

With the data run above, I am getting output of 36 rows (my count) which I am dividing by 31 (days), and expecting a daily average to be 1.161, however my output on each row for the daily average is .032258 (which I've determined to be 1.16 / 36). The non-aggregated columns are in the Group By, but are somehow skewing the daily average.

[image]

If I run a query just on the calculated average `(COUNT(*) * 1.0 / 31 ) AS 'Daily Average'` then I get the correct daily average of 1.161 so I know it has something to do with the Group By. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Running this query 
    `SELECT (COUNT(*) * 1.0 / 31 ) AS 'Daily Average'
     FROM PS_TRANSACTION_INV A, (PS_PURCH_ITEM_ATTR B LEFT OUTER JOIN

      PS_ITEM_MFG C ON  B.SETID = C.SETID AND B.INV_ITEM_ID = C.INV_ITEM_ID ), 
      PS_CM_ACCTG_DIST_D D 
     WHERE ( A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' 
      AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID 
      AND C.PREFERRED_MFG = 'Y' 
      AND A.TRANSACTION_DATE >= '05-01-2018' 
      AND A.TRANSACTION_DATE <= '05-31-2018' 
      AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = D.INV_ITEM_ID 
      AND D.TRANSACTION_GROUP = A.TRANSACTION_GROUP 
      AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = '1')` 
yields the correct results of 1.161, its just when I add it to the query above with the Group By that my results is not correct. This is what I am trying to mimic in the main query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Average of what? Are you trying to get the average row count per day? Try to add another output column of the COUNT(*) value, that may be helpful.

Comment: I am just trying to get the total row count returned and divide by the number of days in a month, 31 in this case.

Comment: I edited the post above to hopefully provide more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've added group by all your columns, count will always have a result of 1, and thus the result that you get.

Easiest way to do what you are asking is to add that second query, as a subquery to your main query, and you can lose the group by then, like this:

```
SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.INV_ITEM_ID, C.MFG_ID, C.MFG_ITM_ID, 
 A.ADJUST_TYPE, A.QTY_BASE, A.UNIT_MEASURE_STD,
 A.DT_TIMESTAMP, B.DESCR254_MIXED, A.TRANSACTION_GROUP, 
 (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.TRANSACTION_DATE,121)), A.DEPTID, B.PRICE_LIST, 
 A.DESTIN_GL_BU,  A.QTY_BASE* B.PRICE_LIST,  
 (SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 / 31
     FROM PS_TRANSACTION_INV A, (PS_PURCH_ITEM_ATTR B LEFT OUTER JOIN
      PS_ITEM_MFG C ON  B.SETID = C.SETID AND B.INV_ITEM_ID = C.INV_ITEM_ID ), 
      PS_CM_ACCTG_DIST_D D 
     WHERE ( A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' 
      AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID 
      AND C.PREFERRED_MFG = 'Y' 
      AND A.TRANSACTION_DATE >= '05-01-2018' 
      AND A.TRANSACTION_DATE <= '05-31-2018' 
      AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT 
      AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = D.INV_ITEM_ID 
      AND D.TRANSACTION_GROUP = A.TRANSACTION_GROUP 
      AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = '1') 
 )  AS 'Daily Average'
FROM PS_TRANSACTION_INV A, (PS_PURCH_ITEM_ATTR B LEFT OUTER JOIN  
 PS_ITEM_MFG C ON  B.SETID = C.SETID AND B.INV_ITEM_ID = C.INV_ITEM_ID ), 
 PS_CM_ACCTG_DIST_D D 
WHERE ( A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' 
 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID 
 AND C.PREFERRED_MFG = 'Y' 
 AND A.TRANSACTION_DATE >= '05-01-2018' 
 AND A.TRANSACTION_DATE <= '05-31-2018' 
 AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT 
 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = D.INV_ITEM_ID 
 AND D.TRANSACTION_GROUP = A.TRANSACTION_GROUP 
 AND A.INV_ITEM_ID = '1')
```

Comment: yes this does yield the results I am expecting! Would there be any alternative method without the use of a sub-query?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no in a single query. I've used either this (when single query), or calculating it and adding it to a variable (if part of stored procedure)

Comment: PS. would appreciate if marked as answered, since it worked for you :)